# OSX Lion - iSight camera terminal usage triggers wake from display sleep?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sleep, isight

I have 3 Macs - a MacBook Pro 15", MacBook Pro 13" & MacBook Air 11".

The 15" stays home all the time, the other 2 are used for mobile usage, so I want to use the 15" for remote video capture or snapshots when I'm not home.  I've been using a command-line tool called "imagesnap" which works great from Terminal (and via SSH) and allows me to set up batch files that run in the background.

However, I have a strange issue where usage of the tool triggers the 15" to wake from display sleep but neither of the other 2 Macs display this behavior.  I don't want to use any more power than necessary so this is rather annoying.

I'm not interested in debgugging the imagesnap tool itself, I don't think that's the issue.  What I want to figure out, though, is what is the best way to determine why one Mac is behaving one way while the other 2 are behaving another?  I've looked at the power settings and can't figure out why the 15" display turns on a moment after I snap an image but the other 2 don't - the settings are pretty much identical.  I've tried to also run similar configurations of running applications.

Is there something in the log files I can look into?  A running process?  A configuration difference to compare?  Or, in case that doesn't solve it, is there a way to suppress the system from waking the display immediately after snapping an image from the webcam?

Answer (score 1):

you could try checking your settings with `pmset -g` in terminal because you have more control there. you might have already solved this one since it's been a year.